Update the nth element of an array on Excel using formulas
I've got an array on A1:An where n will change quite often. I'm trying to write a formmula that replaces the first and second element of the array for the values on cells F1 and F2, and also the nth and n-1th elements need to be replaced for the values in G1 and G2, keeping all the other elements without any changes.
I've tried to append arrays F1:F2 + A3:An-2 + G1:G2, but that was a real pain and nothing I've tried seems to work.
I've also tried to create an auxiliary array like {1,1,0,0,...0,0,0,1,1} to multiply and add stuff together, but that also proved to be pretty challenging.
The important thing, is that I want to be able to hold the new array in a formula, so that I can use it in array formulas.
Thanks!

Maybe VSTACK would be helpful?

that was a real pain and nothing I've tried seems to work. - so what did you try, and why was it a pain? As @BigBen says, VSTACK should do the job. E.g. =VSTACK(F1:F2,A3:An-2,G1:G2). If you can't reference your partial array, use INDIRECT.

use =XMATCH(TRUE,A:A<>"",,-1) to find the last filled cell in your array (it outputs a number, so you know that's the last filled row), add in some INDIRECT(). Like BigBen said, throw in a  VSTACK ; but perhaps post some sample data, so it's clearer what you're trying to achieve.

From what I understand (let me know if I got it wrong, so I can delete this answer and you can edit your post):
=LET(_Data,A:A,
_Start,F1:F2,
_End,G1:G2,
_LastVal,XMATCH(TRUE,_Data<>"",,-1),
_PickRow,(A2:INDIRECT("A"&_LastVal-2)),
_Stack,VSTACK(_Start,_PickRow,_End),_Stack)



Side note: you can use INDEX instead of INDIRECT.

With INDEX, as BigBen also suggested,
=LET(
    a_n, A1:XLOOKUP(TRUE, A:A <> "", A:A, , , -1),
    n, ROWS(a_n),
    i, SEQUENCE(ROWS(a_n)),
    IFS(
        i <= 2,
        INDEX(F1:F2, i),
        i >= n - 1,
        INDEX(G1:G2, 2 - (n - i)),
        TRUE,
        INDEX(a_n, i)
    )
)


